# Processing XML via StreamXmlRecordReader and Pig in parallel

Tags: apache-hadoop, aws

I'm trying to process a single large XML file with many records and then parse each record in parallel using AWS EMR.

```
<records>
  <record>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Jane</name>
  </record>
  <record>
    <id>2</id>
    <name>John</name>
  </record>
</records>
```

I can read in a small XML and loop with `Pig program` step in EMR:

```
DEFINE XPath org.apache.pig.piggybank.evaluation.xml.XPath();

A = LOAD '$INPUT' using org.apache.pig.piggybank.storage.XMLLoader('record') as (x:chararray);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE XPath(x, 'record/id'),XPath(x,'record/name');
dump B;
```

I can also read in the file, broken into records, using a `Streaming program` step with `-inputreader StreamXmlRecordReader,begin=<record>,end=</record>` as an argument.

Currently the Pig script is breaking with the large XML, it works fine on a smaller sample. What I really need is to break this large XML into single records, then parse each record *in parallel* using a chain of Pig (for the XML/XPath) => further custom steps to parse each subsequent output in parallel, how would I do this? How do you organise AWS EMR to run one step, then split into many steps?